# Return a status from nodejs/express REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Does

```
res.status(200)
res.json({
  isSuccess: true
});
```

equals to

```
res.status(200).json({
  isSuccess: true
});
```

?

I'll explain why I ask. 
I build a MEAN app and use mocha for the unit tests.

As I have seen in some tutorial somewhere, I send res as a validation function to check the return values.

Actually res is built out of two functions: status and json. When the BE API changes the status or the json for the response, it actually calls the validation function to check the values.

The reason I ask is that when I do res.status(200).json(...) only the status function is being called. When I use the second method, both function are being called as I intended.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should all be equal:

```
res.status(200);
res.json({});

res.status(200).json({});

res.json({});
```

Answer (score 0):

They might have different internal workings but they both give you the same result when you make API calls. If it's just for testing, it shuold be no problem.